# Majority observations outside confidence interval

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval

I have a time series (called sigma.year), with a length of 100. Its histogram and qqplot shows strong evidence for normality.

I am calculating confidence interval (in R) for sample mean as follows:

```
exp.sigma<-mean(sigma.year)
sd.sigma<-sd(sigma.year)
se.sigma=sd.sigma/sqrt(length(sigma.year))
me.sigma=qt(.995,df=length(sigma.year)-1)*se.sigma
low.sigma=exp.sigma-me.sigma
up.sigma=exp.sigma+me.sigma
```

My problem is 83/100 observations falls outside the confidence interval. Do you have any idea why I have this so? Is this because I have time-series, rather than cross section data? Or, am I calculating conf interval in a wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to evaluate completely without knowing all of your inputs (for example, a dput of sigma.year), but your confidence interval appears to be a confidence interval for the mean. So it is not unexpected that 83/100 observations are outside of a 99% confidence interval about the mean.

To clarify. If `sd.sigma` is the standard deviation of your sample, then you have correctly calculated the 99% confidence interval about the mean.

And again, your data are behaving as you'd expect for a sample of 100 observations drawn from a population with a normal distribution. Here's some code to check that:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
exp.x <- mean(x)
se.x <- sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
q.x <- qt(0.995, df = length(x)-1)
interval <- c(exp.x - se.x*q.x, exp.x + se.x*q.x)
sum(x > interval[1] & x < interval[2])
# will vary, because I didn't set the seed on purpose, but try this
# you'll get a value around 20
```

Comment: ok, so now you're certainly calculating the correct 99% confidence interval about the mean of your data. We can't verify the data itself, but we can answer your question.  If this answer answers your question, please mark it as the answer :)  Thanks!

Comment: I think in the limit as your data set gets large, **none** of the observations will fall within the 95% confidence interval for the mean ...